# Why does text-decoration: underline not work?

Tags: html, css, hover

On a a website I am currently working on, I have issues with underlining links on hover. Although declaring text-decoration: underline on hovering links, it doesn't work properly. I can't explain it myself.

Look at the website itself (it's the links on the bottom right corner): http://nils.zamaitat.de/#contact

It's the same with the dropdown menu "Projects" on the home section: The links that fade in can't handle the underlining properly as well: http://nils.zamaitat.de/#home

This is what I have in my CSS:

```
section.contact .links ul > li a:hover 
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav ul li ul > li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @NitinVarpe `Ctrl + -`

Comment: not in Chrome, though!

Comment: Include sufficient code for reproducing the problem, in the question itself, and describe what you expect and how the actual behavior differs from it. Also list the browser(s) tested and identify on which browsers the problem manifests itself.

Answer (score 4):

You have `text-decoration: none;` in `style.css`. This CSS is telling the browser to render all hyperlinks with no text decoration. You'll need to override that CSS by supplying the `!important` declaration.

So for the links that you would like to be underlined, simply add the `!important` declaration to its corresponding CSS ID or Class.

**Example**

Change from:

```
a.exampleLinkClass{text-decoration:underline}
```

to this:

```
a.exampleLinkClass{text-decoration:underline !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 444 of style.css:

```
.contact div.links ul > li a
```

That's how the links in the bottom right are being initially styled. That means in order to override it, even when triggering it in an altered state, you need to call it by the same identifier inititially used with `:hover` appended to it, or you need to use `text-decoration: underline !important;` to force the rule to take place.

This situation is very common when css is overscoped and overcomplicated. It becomes easy to lose track of what identifier was targeted to which element.

`.contact div.links ul > li a` could be changed to just `.contact .links a` since you're using single level `li` elements and not a dropdown there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS is just fine, no problems there.

Its the font - its not working properly in webkit browsers - It looks fine in firefox. Try changing the font to for example Helvetica and it works fine.

Now why its not working - pfff dunno ;D Never seen that font before.

EDIT: Ahhh its prolly your font-face, you have only supplied a eot file. From css3please.com:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

So you need to supply a woff type also - you can generate it on fontsquirrel.com

Comment: Hmm ... weird. The webfont provides all the formats needed.

Comment: But you are right with Firefox: It works fine there.

Is something wrong with my font-face css? http://jsfiddle.net/2gbd2/

Comment: Seems right - but I cannot see it on your page, the files aren't found on the server.